# Run a tool UI using Python in ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy

I want to find a way to run a tool's UI using arcpy. I know that I can use this code to execute buffer tool

```
import arcpy

roads = "c:/base/data.gdb/roads"
output = "c:/base/data.gdb/roads_Buffer"

# Run Buffer using the variables set above and pass the remaining 
# parameters in as strings
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(roads, output, "distance", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE")
```

This code executes the buffer itself, but I want just display buffer UI just like when we click on buffer. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: It is possible through python-addins, never tried that within a normal Python Script. See this post: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/74093 it uses pythonaddins.GPToolDialog()

Comment: Do you refer to custom script tools? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm

Comment: @AndreasMüller I think you should add that as an answer (with an extra sentence or two)

Comment: @AndreasMüller in fact I am using python-addins and I have some custom tools which I want to run them when user clicks a button,It seems I must uses GPToolDialog();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a short answer, after Majid confirms my assumption, you can use Python-Addins to call a tool by a button-click-event.

```
import pythonaddins
#...skipping more code
def onClick(self):          
    pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(toolPath, "ToolNameFromToolbox")
```

I'm referring to this Post on ESRI's geonet platform: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/74093 and used this in my own addins.